# Unable to stop the timer ticker

Tags: go, timer, goroutine

I have defined few tickers and when I try to stop them, I see below

> undefined: ticker in ticker.Stop
>
> undefined: Q30sticker in Q30sticker.Stop

Code sample:

```
if activenode() {
                    cipaflage = true
                    break

                } else {
                    if cipaflage == true {
                        defer ticker.Stop()
                        defer Q30sticker.Stop()
                        cipaflage = false
                        }
                    continue
                }
```

And I have declared the ticker as below

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(59 * time.Second)
Q30sticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 30).C
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The code you've provided is not sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per the docs [here](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker)

`Ticker` has an exported field `C`.

```
type Ticker struct {
        C <-chan Time // The channel on which the ticks are delivered.
        // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
```

You can receive the "ticks", or heartbeats on the `C` channel, but if you are doing this:

```
Q30sticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 30).C
```

then `Q30sticker` holds a reference to the channel `C` and not the ticker type. It is the `time.Ticker` struct that defines the `Stop` method.

Update your variable to hold the ticker type (by removing `.C`):

```
Q30sticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second * 30)
```

And where you receive from the channel, use the `.` dot syntax to access the channel.

```
<-Q30sticker.C
```

Comment: While this is *an* issue with the posted code, it is not the cause of the issue stated in the question.

Comment: I disagree, `undefined: Q30sticker in Q30sticker.Stop` is a compile time error happening because `<-chan Time` doesn't define a `Stop` method.

Comment: could you explain in detail.

Comment: This is what I attempted to explain above, if anything in the answer doesn't make sense; I can clarify it